# FilePond react multiplefiles upload

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am trying to use the filePound library to upload multiple images, I want to make a http request after that that sends this files to a server. And I have faced an issue, here is my code

```
<FilePondWithPlugins
              ref={pondRef}
              acceptedFileTypes={["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"]}
              dropValidation={true}
              maxFileSize="2MB"
              allowMultiple={true}
              onupdatefiles={async (fileItems) => {
                console.log(fileItems.file);
                console.log(fileItems);
                console.log("here");
                for(let i = 0; i < fileItems.length; i++){
                  await makeRequest(fileItems[i])
                }
              }}
              onaddfile={async (error, fileObj) => {

                console.log(fileObj.file);
                console.log("here");
                console.log(await makeRequest(fileObj.file);
               }}
            />
```

so The problem with `onupdatefiles` is that it is doing all procces the same amount of files I uplload, so if I upload 2 files , it logs this 2 files 2 times and makes 4 requests total.

On the other hand the `onaddfile` logs 2 files once, but makes only one request.
SO my question is following: How can I make it so that it logs 2 files and makes 2 requests to upload file to server?

Any help is apreciated!

Comment: you have `onupdatefiles` and `onaddfile` try removing one and see the difference if any

Comment: Thanks, Rikin, I have putted both them here to demonstrate that I have tried both these methods.

Comment: why not use the FilePond build in server functionality?